# clojure library for SPNEGO/Kerberos-http authentication

Tags: clojure, spnego

I understand this is a long shot but, would there happen to be a clojure library for responding to kerberos over http (aka spnego) requests?

I'm currently looking into using spring-security framework for this but thought i'd ask about a more clojure friendly approach just in case.

Comment: Spring security only handles the application layer, eg once it hits past the servlet request, what container architecture are you using for your application?

Comment: Spring on Tomcat on Centos5.5

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special involved to integrate a clojure app with Spring Security.  However, you are bound by its implementation as a servlet filter, so you cannot easily use it under a  generic http library.  Under a j2ee container, it is a good choice.